# decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python-3.x, decimal

I thought that setting a fixed number of decimal points to all numbers of an array of Decimals, and the new arrays resulting from operations thereof, could be achieved by simply doing:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 5   # 4 decimal points
v = Decimal(0.005)
print(v)
0.005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875
```

However, I get spurious results that I know are the consequence of the contribution of these extra decimals to the calculations. Therefore, as a workaround, I used the round() function like this:

```
C_subgrid= [Decimal('33.340'), Decimal('33.345'), Decimal('33.350'), Decimal('33.355'), Decimal('33.360'), Decimal('33.365'), Decimal('33.370'), Decimal('33.375'), Decimal('33.380'), Decimal('33.385'), Decimal('33.390'), Decimal('33.395'), Decimal('33.400'), Decimal('33.405'), Decimal('33.410'), Decimal('33.415'), Decimal('33.420'), Decimal('33.425'), Decimal('33.430'), Decimal('33.435'), Decimal('33.440'), Decimal('33.445'), Decimal('33.450'), Decimal('33.455'), Decimal('33.460'), Decimal('33.465'), Decimal('33.470'), Decimal('33.475'), Decimal('33.480'), Decimal('33.485'), Decimal('33.490'), Decimal('33.495'), Decimal('33.500'), Decimal('33.505'), Decimal('33.510'), Decimal('33.515'), Decimal('33.520'), Decimal('33.525'), Decimal('33.530'), Decimal('33.535'), Decimal('33.540'), Decimal('33.545'), Decimal('33.550'), Decimal('33.555'), Decimal('33.560'), Decimal('33.565'), Decimal('33.570'), Decimal('33.575'), Decimal('33.580'), Decimal('33.585'), Decimal('33.590'), Decimal('33.595'), Decimal('33.600'), Decimal('33.605'), Decimal('33.610'), Decimal('33.615'), Decimal('33.620'), Decimal('33.625'), Decimal('33.630'), Decimal('33.635'), Decimal('33.640'), Decimal('33.645'), Decimal('33.650'), Decimal('33.655'), Decimal('33.660'), Decimal('33.665'), Decimal('33.670'), Decimal('33.675'), Decimal('33.680'), Decimal('33.685'), Decimal('33.690'), Decimal('33.695'), Decimal('33.700'), Decimal('33.705'), Decimal('33.710'), Decimal('33.715'), Decimal('33.720'), Decimal('33.725'), Decimal('33.730'), Decimal('33.735'), Decimal('33.740'), Decimal('33.745'), Decimal('33.750'), Decimal('33.755'), Decimal('33.760'), Decimal('33.765'), Decimal('33.770'), Decimal('33.775'), Decimal('33.780'), Decimal('33.785'), Decimal('33.790'), Decimal('33.795'), Decimal('33.800'), Decimal('33.805'), Decimal('33.810'), Decimal('33.815'), Decimal('33.820'), Decimal('33.825'), Decimal('33.830'), Decimal('33.835'), Decimal('33.840'), Decimal('33.845'), Decimal('33.850'), Decimal('33.855'), Decimal('33.860'), Decimal('33.865'), Decimal('33.870'), Decimal('33.875'), Decimal('33.880'), Decimal('33.885'), Decimal('33.890'), Decimal('33.895'), Decimal('33.900'), Decimal('33.905'), Decimal('33.910'), Decimal('33.915'), Decimal('33.920'), Decimal('33.925'), Decimal('33.930'), Decimal('33.935'), Decimal('33.940'), Decimal('33.945'), Decimal('33.950'), Decimal('33.955'), Decimal('33.960'), Decimal('33.965'), Decimal('33.970'), Decimal('33.975'), Decimal('33.980'), Decimal('33.985'), Decimal('33.990'), Decimal('33.995'), Decimal('34.000'), Decimal('34.005'), Decimal('34.010'), Decimal('34.015'), Decimal('34.020'), Decimal('34.025'), Decimal('34.030'), Decimal('34.035'), Decimal('34.040'), Decimal('34.045'), Decimal('34.050'), Decimal('34.055'), Decimal('34.060'), Decimal('34.065'), Decimal('34.070'), Decimal('34.075'), Decimal('34.080'), Decimal('34.085'), Decimal('34.090'), Decimal('34.095'), Decimal('34.100'), Decimal('34.105'), Decimal('34.110'), Decimal('34.115'), Decimal('34.120'), Decimal('34.125'), Decimal('34.130'), Decimal('34.135'), Decimal('34.140')]
C_subgrid = [round(v, 4) for v in C_subgrid]
```

I got the values of C_subgrid list by printing it out during execution of my code, and I pasted it here. Not sure where the single quotes come from. This code snipped worked fine in Python2.7, but when I upgraded to Python 3.7 it started raising this error:

```
  File "/home2/thomas/Documents/4D-CHAINS_dev/lib/peak.py", line 301, in <listcomp>
    C_subgrid = [round(v, 4) for v in C_subgrid]  # convert all values to fixed decimal length floats!
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

Strangely, if I run it within ipython it works fine, only within my code it creates problems. Can anybody think of any possible reason?